# spring boot return 403 forbidden when POST request with Keyclaok

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I am using Keycloak to authenticate my spring boot application,

I have create a new realm (CommonServices) with a client (chatting-system)

I have this configuration

```
keycloak:
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8083/auth
  realm: CommonServices
  resource: chatting-system
  public-client: true
  principal-attribute: preferred_username
  use-resource-role-mappings: true
  security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]: user
  ssl-required: external

spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
      database: Chat
      username: saga
      password: password

  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:8083/auth/realms/CommonServices/protocol/openid-connect/certs
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8083/auth/realms/CommonServices
```

and I have configured the security as such:

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .hasRole("user")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
}

@Configuration
public class KeycloakConfig {

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }
}
```

**THE ISSUE**

when I access my GET api everything goes fine but

if I access the POST rest API I get **403 forbidden**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess that's a problem with `CSRF` protection that `Spring Security` enables by default. Try disabling it in your `SecurityConfig` to make sure that's the case.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http
            .csrf().disable() // <- THIS LINE
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**")
            .hasRole("user")
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
}
```

If that's the reason, I recommend to set up proper CSRF protection, as disabling it is time saving in terms of development, but overall is not a good idea in terms of deploying to production.

Comment: by default Keycloak configuration uses tomcat, and I'm using WebFlux hence Netty do you know whether Keycloak works with Netty or not ?

Comment: As long as all your communication is done through HTTP, it shouldn't really matter

Comment: isn't this supposed to be activated only if spring security is in the class path? I am still getting this error even if no spring security is active in my endpoint ...

Comment: @DiegoRamos if you're running your project in Intellij, make sure it does not include spring security in your classpath. You can see it in the first line of the console when you run the application. The reason I'm supposing this might be the case is that sometimes if you have the dependency and then remove it, Intellij still may forget to remove it from classpath, so a maven re-import may be helpful

Comment: Thanks @Carmine, as you mentioned, it was added as a class path entry, even if it had been removed from pom.xml, it was appearing in "References Libraries", even if It was not appearing in "Maven Dependencies"